# Running a variable amount of lines dependent on the number of arguments passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, arguments, discord

I want to run this code with a varying amount of inputs, as I am trying to launch an npm library. My only issue is that I cannot figure out how to accomplish what I am trying to.

Basically I want the function "testfunc(){}" to be able to run a specific line of code, replacing a section of it each time with an argument. Example below:

```
  function testfunc{

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

    console.log(arguments[1]);
    console.log(arguments[2]);
    console.log(arguments[3]);
    console.log(arguments[4]);
    console.log(arguments[5]);
    }

    }
```

Here is an example of what I have right now. I would like to have the user able to change the number of times the message is edited.

```
client.on('message', message => {

if(message.content == '69'){

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function animate() {

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
        message.channel.send(arguments[1]).then((sentMessage) => wait(1*1000).then((waitDone) => sentMessage.edit(arguments[i])))


// message.channel.send(arguments[1]).then((sentMessage) => {
//     wait(1*1000).then((waitDone) => sentMessage.edit(arguments[1])).then((sentMessage) => {
//         wait(1*1000).then((waitDone) => sentMessage.edit(arguments[2])).then((sentMessage) => {
//             wait(1*1000).then((waitDone) => sentMessage.edit(arguments[3])).then((sentMessage) => {
//                 wait(1*1000).then((waitDone) => sentMessage.edit(arguments[4]))
//                 })
//             })
//         })
//     })
// }

}

animate('1','2','3','4')

}}})
client.login(token);
```

I'm sure there is probably a simple answer I'm glossing over here, I've started looking into the idea of doing a while loop, but I can't quite figure it out...

Comment: Just so that I understand your problem correctly - you want to run the sequence of `send`, `wait`, `edit` as often as the length of the arguments of your `animate` function?

Comment: @eol I just need to set the `send` and then `edit` variables to the different arguments, but and then run those as often as the length. `wait` is defined as one second in order to not get rate limited by the API.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it,  will post an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `async/await` this can be greatly simplifed. Basically you just iterate over the function's arguments, and await each of the async calls, before continuing with the next argument:

```
async function animate() {
    // send with the first argument
    const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(arguments[0]);
    // continue editing with the remaining args
    for (let i=1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        await wait(1000);
        await sentMessage.edit(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, only about 2 months into coding. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Happy to help :)